# how to generate dynamic textview in android?

Tags: android, dynamic, textview

something like this i want

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
    Textview tx[i] = new TextView(this);
    tx[i].setText("Data")
    TableRow tr[i] = new TableRow(this);
    tr[i].addView(tx);
    // and then adding table row in tablelayout
}
```

can somebody give me small example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    TextView[] tx = new TextView[10];
    TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[10];
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
        tx[i] = new TextView(this);
        tx[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tx[i].setText("Data")
        tr[i] = new TableRow(this);
        tr[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr[i].addView(tx[i]);
        // and then adding table row in tablelayout
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView[] tx = new TextView[10];
TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[10];
for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
    tx[i] = new TextView(this);
    tx[i].setText("Data")
    tr[i] = new TableRow(this);
    tr[i].addView(tx[i]);
    // and then adding table row in tablelayout
}
```