# How to add textview dynamically in android at particular positiion

Tags: android

[image]

I am new with android. I have add textview dynamically in .java file with text apple but I want to add it on the top. How can I do that.

This is my code......in .jave file

```
  TextView lblname;
  LinearLayout linearlayout;
  lblname = new TextView(this);
  linearlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id. linearlayout);
  linearlayout.addView(lblname);
```

Thank You in advance..

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to generate dynamic textview in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727771/how-to-generate-dynamic-textview-in-android)

Comment: in your .xml file you get ImageView in Linear layout? and you add textView in in Linear Layout is common.?

Comment: where is your linearlayout actually?? is it above the apple image or below it?? place a LinearLayout above the apple image and add the textview to that layout..

Answer (score 0):

Simply specify the index where you want to add the child, as a second parameter for the `addView`.

For example, to add it at the top:

```
linearlayout.addView(lblname, 0);
```

See reference:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View, int)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
lblname = new TextView(this);
lblname.setText("APPLE");
lblname.setId(5); // id should be unique
lblname.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linearlayout.addView(lblname,index);//specify your index
```

Comment: It is not working with my requirement...The textview is still display at the same place. Do you have other solution...

Answer (score 0):

modify your last line to:-

```
linearlayout.addView(lblname, index);
```

replace index with the position you want to add the view i.e, 0 if in the beginning or linearlayout.getChildCount()-1 if prior to the last view in you layout